Does it mean that we don't need a normal assumption for using sandwich estimator in normal linear regression?
According to this post,
the blogger uses the theory of estimating equations to construct the robust sandwich variance estimator.
In this post, it said that:
Now we can begin to start applying the theory of estimating equations. First, under certain regularity conditions, the theory tells that the distribution of the estimator $\hat{\beta}$ converges to that of a (multivariate) normal distribution as the sample size n tends to infinity. Importantly, this holds irrespective of whether the errors $\epsilon=Y-X^{T}\beta$ are normally distributed or not, and also irrespective of whether they have constant variance.
Does it mean that we don't need a normal assumption for using sandwich estimator in normal linear regression?

Yes, it does mean that. Normality gives a simpler proof, and a simpler standard error estimator, but it's not necessary.

But isn’t it true that if there is consequential non-normality (when assuming normality) that will be consequential whether or not you get the variance right?  And variance can be misleading for asymmetric sampling distributions, implying that at least one of two confidence limits will be off.

It's an issue for predictive modelling of $Y$ but not for inference about $\hat\beta$

I'm not getting that.  If the sampling distribution is asymmetric, an unbiased std. error can't fix that and confidence coverage will be off, maybe p-values too.  A standard error is not even a good basis for a confidence interval in highly asymmetric cases.

But the (large-sample) sampling distribution of $\hat\beta$ doesn't depend on whether $Y$ is Normal

Of course.  I’m not interested in sample that large though.
